# How to write my own wrapper in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper

In my other question, I've been trying to find someone who knows where to find free open source OCR library for C#. However, it seems there is only C++ library and obviously, C++ is not C#.

One of the responds suggested to write my own wrapper in C#. I have pretty much no idea how to do it, where to learn to do it, or what it actually is - except I believe it's calling C++ methods in dll by changed method calls, .. that's just assumption, indeed.

Please, help out one more newbie. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a good start here:

[Call Unmanaged Code. Part 1 - Simple DLLImport](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/01/call-unmanaged-code-part-1-simple-dllimport/)

Comment: Link is dead now

Answer (score 3):

If you're wrapping is very simple, you can get away with [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net).  If you actually want managed objects, your easiest solution is probably to write the wrapper in C++/CLI (formerly Managed C++), as that provides a full feature set for managed/unmanaged interop.

Answer (score 1):

here's how I do it [Interop](http://stochfit.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/stochfit/trunk/StochFitMain/StochFit/StochFit/Core/InteropCalcs.cs?revision=116&view=markup). It shows you how to do the simple cases (BOOL to bool) as well as a bit of a harder case (passing a struct with pointers to managed memory). Good luck.