# how to create a C# wrapper class from the C++ tesseract library?

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper, dllimport, tesseract

Please guide me on how to create a C# wrapper to access the methods of the tesseract library which is in C++.

Comment: http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/

Comment: I have tried the below mentioned link,
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tesseract-ocr/3sLKXOTVwyU/28XKruPnFwMJ

Comment: @UweKeim Thank you for your update, My goal is to create a C# wrapper library similar to tessnet2 and i cannot use tessnet2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14180/Using-Unmanaged-C-Libraries-DLLs-in-NET-Applicatio) is a good article on CodeProject you can follow.

> When choosing an approach to reusing unmanaged libraries, you normally
>   have three options:
>
> 1. **IJW** or It Just Works. This is one of the greatest features that .NET
>      Framework has provided to developers. You just recompile the old
>      code on the new .NET platform. No or little changes are necessary.
>      Don't forget though; it works in the C++ language only.
> 2. **COM**. The COM model works on both the unmanaged and managed
>      environments. It's straightforward to perform a COM Invoke on .NET.
>      But, if your unmanaged classes are not COM-ready, you probably won't
>      rewrite all the old code to support COM.
> 3. **P/Invoke** or Platform Invoke. This mechanism allows you to import a
>      class as functions at the attribute level. Basically, you import
>      class methods one by one as individual functions, as you do with
>      Win32 APIs.

For your case I will suggest the [PlaPlatform Invocation Services (PInvoke)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It `allows managed code to call unmanaged functions that are implemented in a DLL`. For example have a look on this MSDN code

```
// PInvokeTest.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class PlatformInvokeTest
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    public static extern int puts(string c);
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    internal static extern int _flushall();

    public static void Main() 
    {
        puts("Test");
        _flushall();
    }
}
```

There is also an older post related to this, you can [check it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749520/how-to-write-my-own-wrapper-in-c).